# Class and id combinator not applying in react project

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

I have created a new react project using create-react-app and the only additional dependency is materials-ui. Im trying to apply some css to divs and these can be targeted using className and id seperately but not using a .class#id combinator.

I thought it could be that other CSS is overriding my stying but inspecting the source in my browser it does not even come up as an applied style.

this is my jsx code,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div id='column-wrapper'>
        <div className='column' id='0'>hello</div>
        <div className='column' id='1'>world</div>
        <div className='column'></div>
        <div id='test'></div>
    </div>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is my css,

```
.column#0 {
    background-color: green;
    content: "";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't accept numbers, if you change it to string ...abc. It will work.

Comment: @AnilKumar thank you very much, I had no idea numbers were not accepted.